# SNMP : with not root user

Tags: linux, snmp

I normally do snmptraps and other net-snmp commands without problems with root session, but when i try to execute same commads with a normal user i obtain follow errors:

```
Cannot rename /var/lib/net-snmp/snmpapp.conf to /var/lib/net-snmp/snmpapp.0.conf

Cannot unlink /var/lib/net-snmp/snmpapp.conf

read_config_store open failure on /var/lib/net-snmp/snmpapp.conf

read_config_store open failure on /var/lib/net-snmp/snmpapp.conf

read_config_store open failure on /var/lib/net-snmp/snmpapp.conf
```

I try to search for a .conf file for add the necessary permisions to all net-snmp to a normal user but i don't find it exactly what to do, for fixing this problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced similar issue and resolved it by following a discussion at http://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/bugs/1706/. I think the pith of the problem has to do with running the snmptrap command with an unprivileged user. In which case a user specific configuration should be created by adding the following line:

```
persistentDir /home/user/.snmp_persist
```

in ~/.snmp/snmp.conf

After you run snmptrap you should see something similar to:

```
Creating directory: /home/user/.snmp_persist
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the snmptrapd man page shows the following:

> Note: the default is to listen on UDP port 162 on all IPv4  interfaces.
>          Since  162  is  a  privileged  port, snmptrapd must typically be run as
>          root.

I am not familiar with snmpapp.conf but I would start with looking at the permissions for /var/lib/net-snmp/snmpapp.conf. What distro are you running and are you using any sort of frontend to SNMP?

Comment: Using fedora core 19, i don't use a frontend snmp i sent snmtptraps automatically using bash scripts.

Comment: OK. Is the output above from your scripts? It looks like the snmpapp file is being renamed then replaced with something different or a modified version of the original. This would point to an issue with permissions. With RedHat flavored distros SELinux could also be an issue. You could use setfacl to give a normal account write privileges on the required files to see if that fixes things.